# Installed OpenSSH on Mint 17 but it doesn't seem to be running

Tags: ssh, openssh

So I've installed OpenSSH on Mint rafaela 17.2, but it doesn't seem to be running when using the modified config file.

Not sure why service says its up, but I don't have a PID, don't have a listener, and can't connect at all...

```
service --status-all shows [-] ssh.
```

`service ssh start` returns start:

```
Job is already running:ssh
```

`ssh localhost` returns connection refused

`ps ax | grep ssh` returns only the `ssh-agent`.

`ss -lnp | grep ssh` shows the gnome-keyring and ssh-agent listening, but not the ssh daemon. (`grep sshd` returns nothing at all)

I followed this for the setup - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

Any thoughts? I've been searching for hours on how to start the damn service and getting nothing.

Edit (More Info)

Played around some more, switched back to the default sshd config file and running service ssh restart returns ssh stop/waiting and ssh start/running, process

When I put the modified config file back in place and did a restart, no process ID comes up.

Looked at the log file, when trying to restart sshd with the new config file I see the following-

```
Aug 29 17:58:25 serenity kernel: [ 3867.828744] init: ssh main process (6151) terminated with status 255
Aug 29 17:58:25 serenity kernel: [ 3867.828754] init: ssh main process ended, respawning
Aug 29 17:58:31 serenity kernel: [ 3873.631306] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.8 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=142 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=65238 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=122 
Aug 29 17:58:31 serenity kernel: [ 3873.631323] [UFW ALLOW] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.8 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=142 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=65238 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=122 
Aug 29 17:58:31 serenity kernel: [ 3873.631346] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=10.0.0.8 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=142 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=65238 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=17500 DPT=17500 LEN=122 
Aug 29 17:58:39 serenity kernel: [ 3881.610999] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:00:1d:d1:7a:3c:91:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Default and new config files changes listed

```
diff sshd_config (NEW CONFIG) sshd_config.bckp (DEFAULT CONFIG) 
24c24
< LogLevel VERBOSE
---
> LogLevel INFO
27c27
< LoginGraceTime 30
---
> LoginGraceTime 120
52c52
< PasswordAuthentication no 
---
> #PasswordAuthentication yes
71,72c71,72
< MaxStartups 2:30:10
< Banner /etc/issue.net
---
> #MaxStartups 10:30:60
> #Banner /etc/issue.net
89,94d88
< 
< AllowTcpForwarding no
< 
< AllowUsers <username>
< 
< ForwardAgent no
```

Comment: Did you install `openssh` or `openssh-server`? You need the latter package if you want to connect to your machine through ssh.

Comment: Used openssh-server

Comment: Run `service ssh restart` and see what appears in the system logs. I'm not sure which log file Mint uses, look in `/var/log` for files that change when you run that command and edit your question to add the log entries generated at that time.

Comment: the process is called `sshd`. Really there is not such a process running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of figured it out.  Obviously something in the config file was stopping the server from starting.

After implementing each file change one line at a time, finally found it was the ForwardAgent no line in the config that was causing problems.

After some more digging, found that you could start the daemon direct instead of through the services to see if you were getting an error message.

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -Ddp 10222
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 90: Bad configuration option: ForwardAgent
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I don't know why the ForwardAgent setting there is causing issues, but commenting that out let me finally run the server.

Comment: Is `ForwardAgent` acutually documented in `man sshd_config`? On my Mint 17 it is not.

Comment: Its not. That's what I get for not looking in the man page.  Its the first time I've tried setting one up, I must have seen it on a setup guide and didnt realize it was talking about ssh_config.